# Relative width of rotated element

Tags: css, transform

I have an anchor (`a`) that has `height: 40%` and `width: 20px`. Its child element is a span to which I have applied `transform: rotate(90deg)` and `transform-origin: left bottom`.

I want the dimensions of the span to be the same as the parent, so I specify `width: 100%`. However, when rotated the span loses those dimensions. I can specify the text width with a hardcoded pixel value, but I want this span to be flexible, relative to the available screen size.

[Fiddle demonstrating this issue](http://jsfiddle.net/RPbKD/)

I know I can set the width of the span with JavaScript, but I want to avoid having to do so if at all possible. Does anyone know of a CSS-only solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Now define** `white-space: nowrap;`

```
.pulltab > a > span {white-space: nowrap;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RPbKD/1/)**

Comment: Doh! I could have sworn I applied that at some point, but clearly I hadn't done so correctly.  But this does indeed work, thank you!